# How to add Any API Key into the Flutter Application

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I was trying to fetch Unsplash API into one of my image application that i want to build. Search a lot but cound't find a best answer to do that.

Comment: Just make a dart file and call it whatever you want and the add a variable and the API key.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent code if there is already a package for this :

Github: https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Flutter-Global-Config

Pub Dev : https://pub.dev/packages/global_configuration

Install :

```
dependencies:
  global_configuration: ^1.2.0
```

## Load configuration fro path at app start

Create a file anywhere inside your app. Normally add the json file to your assets folder.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:global_configuration/global_configuration.dart';

void main(){
  GlobalConfiguration().loadFromPath("/path/file.json");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
}
```

## Access the key

Instatiate the GlobalConfiguration class and call any get($key) method.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:global_configuration/global_configuration.dart';

class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {

    CustomWiget(){
        // Access the config in the constructor
        print(GlobalConfiguration().getString("key1"); // prints value1
    }

    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // Access the config in the build method
        return new Text(GlobalConfiguration().getString("key2")); // prints value2
     }
}
```